# Excel 2007 Column Offset subtraction in Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel-2007, conditional-formatting

The following formula in conditional formatting is not behaving the same as it does in a cell of a worksheet:

```
 IF(OFFSET(INDIRECT("RC",FALSE),0,4-COLUMN())="Answer Changed",TRUE,FALSE)
```

I am applying this formula to 3 columns of cells, and need it to look at the 4th column of each respective row. In a cell in a worksheet this works as expected. Is there some trick to this, as I know that the row and column functions work in other conditional formatting formula's I use (i.e., `IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=1,TRUE,FALSE)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want columns A through C to be formatted if column D contains "Answer Changed."  If that that's the case, and assuming your data starts in Row 2, you can accomplish this by picking cells A2:C2 and entering this conditional formatting formula:

```
=$D2="Answer Changed"
```

Then just copy it down as far as needed.

Note that you don't need to use an IF statement.  Condtional formatting evaluates whether the statement is TRUE and applies the formatting if it is.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Doug Glancy. This worked, but am still wondering why the 3-COLUMN() didn't work in this formula, but the opposite function works in IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=1,TRUE,FALSE)

Comment: I'm not sure.  Frankly I don't understand your formula.  It could be because 3-Column() would be 0 for column C.  Anyways, I'm glad this worked for you!

Comment: Oops, I copied it wrong, it is supposed to be 4-COLUMN(), so that's exactly what it is supposed to be :) If it is looking at column 1, it needs to look 3 column across; Column 2 needs to look 2 column across, and the final column needs to look 1 column across.